# TypeError : ...map is not a function - react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In my *react.js* application I have a function like this :

```
state={
   c:[]
}


classRoom(classRooms)
{
    if(classRooms!==null)
    {
        const updatedClass = classRooms.map((classRoom)=>{
            return <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"as"} classID={"asdsa"} />;
            //return <li>{classRoom}</li>;
        });
    }
}
```

In my `render` method I have :

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
                            {this.classRoom(this.state.c)}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

`c` is defined in state, it is an array.

But it gives me error, saying : **classRooms.map is not a function**

Comment: And `classRooms` /  `this.state.c` (imho a _terrible_ name for a variable) is what?

Comment: This error usually happens when the object you are trying to map is not an array. Can you check if `c` is an array?

Comment: `c` is an array, I've console logged and checked it

Comment: The question is very vague, but classRooms is probably not an array

Comment: `classRooms` doesn't seem to be an array or anything that implements a `map` method. It's also not `null` or (presumably) `undefined`. Impossible to say *what* it actually is, though.

Comment: what is the value of classRooms?
empty string will give you the same error :|

'''.map(i=>i).

I agree with you @VLAZ

Comment: array for sure , see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYNyZ.png)

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to `const updatedClass = classRooms.map((classRoom)=>{` and see what the value of `classRooms` is please? I imagine it's not an array. You might want to update your if statement to address this.

Comment: I have changed the state, now I have defined it as an array... like this : `state={c:[]}`...

But it renders nothing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and the stackblitz link, the problem was that you were not returning value from inside the function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class ClassRoomUnit extends Component{
    displayName;
    classID;
    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            {this.props.displayName}
            {this.props.classID}
          </div>

        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {

  state={
    c:[1,2,3]
  }

  classRoom(classRooms)
    {
        console.log(classRooms);
        if(classRooms!==null)
        {
            const updatedClass = classRooms.map((classRoom)=>{
                return <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"as"} classID={"asdsa"} />;
            });
        }
        return updatedClass;
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        dynamic list start
        {this.classRoom(this.state.c)}
        dynamic list end

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Ok, I have changed `c` in state like this : `c : []`...

Now it works without crashing, but it renders nothing

Comment: where are you setting the values you want it to show?

Comment: it would now obviously render nothing, since now the map is on an empty array. Set the data you want using setState() or initialize c with the actual array than `[]`

Comment: You have array in Home.js, how are you passing it into this component?

Comment: If the data is loaded in c of Home.js and this is another component, then you should send the state c from Home.js to this component as props and not manage the state in this component. Share the entire codebase if you are not sure where the error is.

Comment: currently i'm not passing, using some default value : `<ClassRoomUnit displayName={"as"} classID={"asdsa"} />` If it renders something , then I will move onto passing something

Comment: without value in the array the map will not enter the loop. Put some dummy value in c then, instead of `[]`. make it `[1,2,3]` or anything. if you arent using the values from inside it

Comment: create a stackblitz with your application. The problem is somewhere else and not in this area

Comment: Can you share a sandbox?

Comment: here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7wol77) link

Comment: you weren't returning anything from inside the classroom function

Comment: and move the ClassRoomUnit component to before the other component. Components should be defined before use.